# Find closest sibling using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, siblings, closest

Given the following DOM

```
<ul>
     <li data-id="1">
     <li data-id="2">
     <li data-id="3">
     <li data-id="1">
</ul>
```

We need to find the closest `<li>`-Element with `data-id="1"` to the one with data-id="3"

We tried:

```
$('[data-id=3]').siblings('[data-id=1]').first()
```

which of course returns the *first* in DOM and not the *closest*

We also tried:

```
$('[data-id=3]').closest('[data-id=1]')
```

which does not work as it's only returning ancestors.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: How are you defining 'closest' in this case? The element with the closest index to the current?

Comment: You want before or after sibling?

Comment: Do you actually mean next? not closest?

Comment: I actually mean the *closest* element compared to the starting point, so, the last data-id=1 is closer if starting point is data-id=3, the first data-id=1 is closer if starting point is data-id=2

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, you are absolutely right!

Comment: @RaphaelJeger I added an answer for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery getting closest sibling element from $(this) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612629/jquery-getting-closest-sibling-element-from-this-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [**nextUntil()**](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) and [**prevUntil()**](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) you can calculate which direction has the *closest* sibling and then determine whether to use [**next()**](https://api.jquery.com/next/) or [**prev()**](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```js
var nextLength = $('[data-id="3"]').nextUntil('[data-id="1"]').length;
var prevLength = $('[data-id="3"]').prevUntil('[data-id="1"]').length;
var closestSibling;
if (nextLength > prevLength) {
  closestSibling = $('[data-id="3"]').prev('[data-id="1"]');
} else {
  closestSibling = $('[data-id="3"]').next('[data-id="1"]');
}
console.log(closestSibling.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-id="1">second closest</li>
  <li data-id="2"></li>
  <li data-id="3"></li>
  <li data-id="1">first closest</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks. Your solution is the most readable so we work with this.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the `data-id="1"` element nearest to the currently selected based on their index, you can first sort the elements by the proximity of their index, then get the first. Try this:

```js
var currentIndex = $('[data-id="3"]').index();
$('[data-id="1"]').sort(function (a, b) {
    var aDelta = Math.abs($(a).index() - currentIndex);
    var bDelta = Math.abs($(b).index() - currentIndex);
    return aDelta > bDelta;
}).first().addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li data-id="1">1</li>
    <li data-id="2">2</li>
    <li data-id="3">3</li>
    <li data-id="1">1</li>
</ul>
```

To test it works, change `data-id="3"` in the selector to `data-id="2"`. You'll see the first `li` with `data-id="1"` gets the class applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the closest by looping through the siblings and finding the minimum index relative to the current element index i.e $('[data-id=3]') :

```
var mainIndex = $('[data-id=3]').index('li');
    var minDif = 999;
    var closestIndex = 0;

    $('[data-id=3]').siblings('[data-id=1]').each(function(index)

      if(Math.abs($(this).index('li') - mainIndex) < minDif)
      {
        minDif = Math.abs($(this).index('li') - mainIndex);
        closestIndex = $(this).index('li');
      }

    });


    $('[data-id]').eq(closestIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice simple jQuery plugin for your needs is one way to go:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.closestSiblingByIndex = function(selector) {
        var thisIndex = this.index();
        var siblings = this.siblings(selector).map(function(i,e){
            return {
                element: $(this),
                diff: Math.abs($(this).index() - thisIndex)
            }
        }).get().sort(function(a,b){return a.diff-b.diff;});
        if(siblings.length == 0){
            return $();
        }
        else{
            return siblings[0].element
        }
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Then the usage would be, for example:

```
$("li[data-id='3']").closestSiblingByIndex("li[data-id='1']");
                    .css('background-color','red')
```

of course, in this example changing that to:

```
$("li[data-id='2']").closestSiblingByIndex("li[data-id='1']");
                    .css('background-color','green')
```

will highlight the other `li`.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/u4b8w9dg/1/