# jQuery getting closest sibling element from $(this) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide the span closest to the button clicked and also hide the button.

The html goes like this

```
<!-- the div will be looped using php -->
<!-- this will only be a general idea of the code as the actual is very long and messy -->
<div>       
  <form><!-- This is like the head section -->
    <div>
        <div> <!-- some divs -->
            <button class="btn"></button> <!-- where i want it to work -->
                <div></div><!-- make this 5 times -->
            <span>content to hide</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>      
  <div><!-- Comments to the head are here -->
    <button class="btn"></button><!-- button where it works -->
    <span>contains the comments</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next("span").hide();
});
```

I've tried the following below:

```
1. $(this).next("span").hide(); 
2. $(this).closest("span").hide();
```

It only works if I call all the span elements.

EDIT: the span is quite far as there are other elements like 5-10 elements before we reach the span.

Comment: closest looks up the tree, not at siblings

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what you need: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8yzw6kg5/)

```
$(this).nextAll("span").first().hide();
```

`nextAll()` will look at all the next siblings (rather than just the first next one), and then we only want the first span that is found... `first()` achieves that

also, `closest()` will not work as it is looking up the tree, not at siblings.

Comment: Nice :) I had not heard of `nextAll` before.

Comment: I know this will work. But it doesn't seem to work in my case, where I want it to work at least. I have other button-span elements and it only works there. Really weird

Comment: You must have something off with your DOM, could you show an example that is more representative?

Comment: @iamDevlin your button is within your form which is submitting the form. you can prevent default like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8yzw6kg5/1/ (assuming you don't want to actually submit the form considering you are trying to change the dom)

Comment: @smerny still no luck. i also tried removing the form tags. thanks though. will upvote this answer.

Comment: @iamDevlin... hmm... it's working in the example so something is different. If I were to guess, maybe the span is actually a child of a sibling rather than a direct sibling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89833/discussion-between-smerny-and-iamdevlin).

Answer (score -1):

EDIT 2: this answer selects the first siblings span, not the first sibling span after the button. The answer above using `$(this).nextAll('span').first().hide()` is the best answer.

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings("span").first().hide();
});
```

`closest()` looks up the DOM tree, `find()` looks down, and `siblings()` is what you're looking for.

Edit 1: added `first()` after `siblings()` to only select the first one

Comment: That will hide *all* sibling `span`s, before and after. OP is looking for the *next* `span`.

Comment: @PaulRoub thanks for pointing that out, just updated my answer.

Comment: New version would hide the first sibling in the list, not the first sibling *following* the button.

Comment: @PaulRoub thanks, I edited to include the correct answer but left mine anyway for the info on `closest`, `find`, and `siblings`

Answer (score -2):

you can try this way:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var _that=$(this)
    _that.hide();
    _that.parent().find('*').eq(_that.index()+2).hide();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3z5oyc4n/

+2 is for each element after your .btn (+1 = div, +2 = span)

Comment: As per the existing *already downvoted* answer, the position of the span is not fixed.

Comment: not my fault is code posted is not complet ! and my answer works ;)

Comment: Question clearly states "closest" not "after 2" and the edit: "the span is quite far as there are other elements like 5-10 elements".  Answers shouldn't fit a specific derived example based on the *derived code alone*.

Comment: or maybe it is the html code who is not as it should :P

Comment: this is quite funny. but no. it will not work as the target element is not fixed at 2 or 3 elements.